# How can I fix a div so that it does not move with the overflow-y?

Tags: html, css, saas

I have a total of three wrappers in which there is a div with the text No Data found! Here is what I want to achieve: User should be able to scroll vertically and horizontally in the table and this text should remain fixed. This also works! But now I scroll down outside the wrapper with overflow-y in the browser so the text moves down with it. How can I solve this problem?

My Code:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


  .no-data-found-message1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .no-data-found-message2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 85%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .no-data-found-message3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message1">
          <span class="no-data-found-text1">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message2">
          <span class="no-data-found-text2">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message3">
          <span class="no-data-found-text3">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

My work in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wbo3xLj/35/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fixed` position give it `absolute`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.fixed-message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
      <th>Third Column</th>
      <th>Fourth Column</th>
      <th>Five Column</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="fixed-message">
    No Data Found!
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
      <th>Third Column</th>
      <th>Fourth Column</th>
      <th>Five Column</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="fixed-message">
    No Data Found!
  </div>
</div>

<!-- THIRD -->

<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
      <th>Third Column</th>
      <th>Fourth Column</th>
      <th>Five Column</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="fixed-message">
    No Data Found!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use position `absolute` instead of `fixed` . It will solve your problem then position according to need .

It will be better and easy if you position **No data found** inside `<table>` element and do position of table as `relative` and **No Data found** as `absolute` . Now you can easily position it according to your table position

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


  .no-data-found-message1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .no-data-found-message2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .no-data-found-message3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120%;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .no-data-found-text3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message1">
          <span class="no-data-found-text1">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message2">
          <span class="no-data-found-text2">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>
     <th>Fourth Column</th>
    <th>Five Column</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Show message, if no data found -->
        <div class="no-data-found-message3">
          <span class="no-data-found-text3">
            No data found!
          </span>
        </div>
</div>
```